# One route working and another not working

Tags: php, laravel

I have these two routes:

```
Route::get('delete/{user}', array('as' => 'delete', 'uses' => 'AdminController@getDeleteUser'));
Route::get('delete/{article}', array('as' => 'delete', 'uses' => 'AdminController@getDeleteArticle'));
```

If I put '`delete/{user}`' first then its working. If I put it below '`delete/{article}`' them working delete article. How can I make them both work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

anything between curly braces is a wildcard parameter, so declaring a route with 'delete/{user}' means anything after 'delete/' will work same as that route, so to achieve what you want do like this

```
Route::get('delete/user/{id}', array('as' => 'deleteUser', 'uses' => 'AdminController@getDeleteUser'));
Route::get('delete/article/{id}', array('as' => 'deleteArticle', 'uses' => 'AdminController@getDeleteArticle'));
```

also you can use regular expression for same route like this

```
Route::get('delete/{user}', function ($name) {
    return "a";
})->where('name', 'regular expression here');
Route::get('delete/{article}', function ($id) {
    return "b";
})->where('id', 'regular expression here');
```

Comment: Route [delete] not defined. What to do next ? NVM! I fixed it ! thanks

Comment: check your route name,if you have used my code sample then route name are 'deleteUser' & 'deleteArticle', if you want those route in your view or anywhere else you can use them by these route name

Comment: i think you are still using route name 'delete' in your view

Answer (score 1):

You should redesign your API.
As it looks, you would do better if you would have routes such as

```
Route::get('user/delete/{id}', array('as' => 'deleteUser', 'uses' => 
    'AdminController@getDeleteUser'));
    Route::get('article/delete/{id}', array('as' => 'deleteArticle', 'uses' => 'AdminController@getDeleteArticle'));
```

You had 2 named routes with the same name.